# How can I find distinct data in MongoDB after using find()

Tags: mongodb

So I am getting this as output, I need only `catalog_id` as distinct as some of the **catalog_id** are duplicates.

```
db.catalog_product.find({product_id:{$in:["5a818d72590b65042559e2d4","5a818d9a590b65042649d966","5a81dd83590b65042559e2dd"]}},{catalog_id:true}).pretty();

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a818d72590b65042559e2d5"),
        "catalog_id" : "5a8127ab590b65042649d942"
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a818d72590b65042559e2d6"),
        "catalog_id" : "5a8127ab590b65042649d942"
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a818d9a590b65042649d967"),
        "catalog_id" : "5a8127ab590b65042649d942"
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a818d9a590b65042649d968"),
        "catalog_id" : "5a8127ab590b65042649d942"
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a81dd83590b65042559e2de"),
        "catalog_id" : "5a813778590b65042649d94c"
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use `db.catalog_product.distinct("catalog_id", {product_id:{$in:["5a818d72590b65042559e2d4","5a818d9a590b65042649d966","5a81dd83590b65042559e2dd"]}}).pretty();`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try aggregate? You can group items based on a key i.e all distinct. Sample query would look like,

```
db.catalog_product.aggregate([
        {$match: {product_id: {$in:["5a818d72590b65042559e2d4","5a818d9a590b65042649d966","5a81dd83590b65042559e2dd"]}},
        {"$group": { "_id": "$catalog_id", "cid": {$first: "$_id"} }, //distinct here
        {$project: { "_id": '$cid', "catalog_id": "$_id"}}
]).pretty();
```

Note: This is an alternate aggregate way to find distinct items. Go with **veeram's** solution in the comments if you're looking for a cleaner way.